# Error while testing question on Java multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was coding some sample examples of Java questions on Multi-dimensional arrays to get an understanding on its initialization and accessibility. I copied the code syntax as in the example but am not able to understand the how to decode the code.

Following the example, I tried to get an understanding on the initialization of the multi-dimensional array. I couldn't grasp the syntax logic and made just one change to the code to test my understanding, the example was initially to get the output of `String value = exampleStr[0];`. I changed it to `String value = exampleStr[0][0];` which gave out the error.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String exampleStr[] = new String[][] 
      {
          {null,null,null}, 
          new String[] {"a","b","c"}, // not sure what this mean
          {new String()} // not sure of this too

      }[0]; 
// what does the whole block actually mean in a compiler/logic sense ?

      String exampleStr3[] = {null};

// this is where the compiler error came!
      String value = exampleStr[0][0];

// shows 3 for this code when error line is commented out
      System.out.println(exampleStr.length); 

      System.out.println(value);


    }
}
```

In the example, the syntax is `String value = exampleStr[0];` which outputs `null`,  I changed it to `String value = exampleStr[0][0];` and got the error.
Why am I getting the error and could someone explain to me the behavior of the code/compiler in regards to this code's syntax. How is the array structure

Comment: The `exampleStr` variable is a one-dimensional String array, and so it makes no sense to the Java compiler (and to me) you're trying to use it as if it were a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: you may think about accepting an answer now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you are first declaring a 1-dimensional array `exampleStr[]`. Then, you are creating a 2-dimensional array, but are subscripting it with a 0, i.e., you are selecting the array at index 0, the array containing the null elements.

`exampleStr[0][0]` => with the first `[0]` you are selecting the first element at index 0, a null type. The second `[0]` would be called on that element, which is a null type and therefore not valid.

Essentially, you are not creating a 2-dimensional array in the first place.

Change your code to this and it will work:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String exampleStr[][] = new String[][]
            {
                    {null,null,null},
                    // creates a 1-d String[], -> {"a", "b", "c"} is enough
                    new String[] {"a","b","c"},
                    // creates an array containing an empty string, -> {""} would be equivalent
                    {new String()} 

            };

    String exampleStr3[] = {null};

    String value = exampleStr[0][0];

    System.out.println(exampleStr.length);

    System.out.println(value);
}
```

EDIT: I added answers to the questions in the comments of the above code segment.

Comment: You mean to say that, it is possible for us to pass a M-D array to a 1-D array ? 
From this example, I am creating a 1-D array, array[] and assigning it a value of arrays ? If that is the case, how would I then be able to access the string array "a","b","c" ? When I tried `exampleStr[1]` I got an array out of bounds error.
 
If I were to change it to `exampleStr[][]`, I am able to access the "a" using `exampleStr[1][0]`

Comment: Not exactly. During an assignment statement, e.g., `String a = "a";` everything on the right side of the `=` is evaluated first. 

In your example, you are first creating a 2-d array, but are then selecting one of the arrays in your 2-d array. This selection, is a 1-d array, which then gets assigned to your `exampleStr[]`.

`String exampleStr[][] = { {"a", "b"} , {"c", "d"} }; // this assings a 2-d array`
You can then select one of the 2 arrays within by `exampleStr[0] // selects {"a", "b"}` or `exampleStr[1] // selects {"c", "d"}`.

Comment: In your example, you are selecting one of the arrays in your 2-d array, BEFORE the assignment, which is correct in your case, since you declared `exampleStr[]` as a 1-d array, which has to be initialized with a 1-d array. In your case, you selected the array at position 0: `{null, null, null}` by writing `[0]` at the end of your 2-d array, thus you assign only one of the arrays, the one containing the null values, to `exampleStr[]`. Since this is a 1-d array, you can select one of the elements with `exampleStr[index]`, but can't further index into it, because you have selected a null element.

Comment: Further, you cannot index a null element or a string element using `[index]`. For a string, you'd have to call a method, such as `charAt(index)`, e.g., `String a = "abc";` => `a.charAt(0);` which would return the character at index 0, which is `a`.

I hope that helps and sorry for the long comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code meant that your create a 2-dimensionnal array but only keep the first box (using the `[0]` at the end), so you could read its first element with `exampleStr[0]` **but** `exampleStr[0][0]` is not possible because `exampleStr[0]` is not an array, so you can't access something into it using an index

```
String exampleStr[] = new String[][] 
  {
      {null,null,null}, 
      new String[] {"a","b","c"}, 
      {new String()} 
  }[0];
```

If we split it, it look slike

```
String array[][] = new String[][] 
  {
      {null,null,null}, 
      new String[] {"a","b","c"}, 
      {new String()} 
  };
String exampleStr[] = array[0]; // which is the {null,null,null} part
```

---

*Details for the 2-dim array and the details into it:*

First, to get it working, `exampleStr` should be a 2-dimensionnal array with `[][]`

So there double `[]` so it's a 2 dimensionnal array of type `String`, which means, that you have an outer array, and each box can contain an (inner) array of String

Here you have, for each box of the outer array:

1. `{null, null, null}` an array of three times the `null` element
2. `new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}` an array of 3 `String`, can be reduced in `{"a", "b", "c"}`
3. `{new String()}` an array of one empty `String`, same as `{""}`

   ```
   String[][] exampleStr = new String[][]{
           {null, null, null},
           new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}, // not sure what this mean
           {new String()} // not sure of this too
   };
   ```

Then `exampleStr[0][0]` means accessing the first element of the first box

Comment: I don't agree with your first statement. Leave exampleStr as a 1-D array and don't try to use as a 2-D one, and things will work just fine. I think that this is an exercise to get the OP to understand the difference between a 1-D and 2-D array, and how rows of a 2-D array are 1-D arrays themselves.

Comment: Why should it be a two-dimensional array? You don't know what the example was trying to show.

Comment: You still might want to remove the erroneous first part of your answer, as pointed out by both @JamesKPolk and myself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've changed the order, to only talk the 2-dim part as a supplement

Comment: OK, I suppose that's better

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels because the OP also asked for explanation of what's inside the 2D array

Comment: The question wanted to know the value of exampleStr[0], which was null.

I got confused with the syntax `String[] exampleStr = new String[][] {{null,null,null},new String[]{"a","b","c"},{new String()}}[0];` , what does it actually mean, How is the array created here, the syntax is kinda new to me. Would I be able to access the "a"

I had always assumed, to create a 2-D array, we need to use two square brackets, so when I changed the code to `String[][] exampleStr = new String[][] {{null,null,null},new String[]{"a","b","c"},{new String()}};` it works as expected.

Comment: @ArvindVijayarooban  so now it’s ok ? Or you have other question ?

Comment: I am okay now, I have a better understanding with the answers given, I just have one doubt to clarify in the original code `String[] exampleStr = new String[][] {{null,null,null},new String[]{"a","b","c"},{new String()}}[0];` the [0] in the end , means that I am assigning the value to the first column which is the [0] ,
Does that mean I am not actually passing the String[] and new String() to the array and they're not actually accessible ?

Comment: @ArvindVijayarooban exactly, look my edit, I've split it in 2 operations ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a weird example, where did you find such a thing? I believe what is going on is that exampleStr is actually a one-dimensional array, so there is no exampleStr[0][0].

To start with there are not really multi-dimensional arrays in Java as there are in languages like C#, but there are arrays of arrays. The curly bracket syntax is a way of initializing a data structure.

```
String exampleStr[] = new String[][] // This declares an array of arrays.
      {
          {null,null,null}, // first column values
          new String[] {"a","b","c"}, // second column values
          {new String()} // empty string is only element added to third column

      }[0]; // This initializes exampleStr to the first column values above.
```

exampleStr is a one-dimensional array of length 3, whose elements are null, null, and null. You would access those values as exampleStr[0], exampleStr[1], and exampleStr[2]. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Found it in a Java exercise book, the example wanted to know the output of `exampleStr[0]` which is null. 

I was not able to understand what was happening with the declaration because when I tried to access the "a" using `String value = exampleStr[1][0];` I got the error _array required, but String found_ , Would the value "a","b", "c" be accessible in this code ?

Comment: You're initializing a 1-d array with the first column, (column 0) of a 2-d array. To access 'a', 'b', or 'c', you'd have to initialize `exampleStr[] = new String[][]{ ... }[1]`.